# Drag an image onto other and it transforms into another image

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

i am creating an android app in which i would drag an image onto other and it will transform into an other image

i have implemented the drag and drop feature here :-

```
package com.example.draganddrop;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.myimage1).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.myimage2).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.myimage3).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.myimage4).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.topleft).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    findViewById(R.id.topright).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    findViewById(R.id.bottomleft).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    findViewById(R.id.bottomright).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

  }

  private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
      if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
    Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
      int action = event.getAction();
      switch (event.getAction()) {
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        // Do nothing
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
        v.setBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
        v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
        // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
        View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
        ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        owner.removeView(view);
        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
        container.addView(view);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
        v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
      default:
        break;
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my activity_main.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:columnWidth="300dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topleft"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topright"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomleft"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomright"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</GridLayout>
```

Now how can i drag and drop an image onto other and it will transform into other image

Comment: possible duplicate of [i am creating an android app in which i would drag an image onto other and it will transform into an other image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411491/i-am-creating-an-android-app-in-which-i-would-drag-an-image-onto-other-and-it-wi)

Comment: This was my question only !!

Comment: Duplicate Question. Please Check the following link [Click here.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247050/how-to-drag-images-from-one-imageview-and-drop-to-another-image-view